# php's explode array index

Tags: php, arrays

Using php's explode with the following code

```
$data="test_1, test_2, test_3";
$temp= explode(",",$data);
```

I get an array like this

```
array('0'=>'test_1', '1'=>'test_2', 2='test_3')
```

what I would like to have after explode

```
array('1'=>'test_1', '2'=>'test_2', 3='test_3')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could something like this :

```
$temp = array_combine(range(1, count($temp)), array_values($temp));
```

uses [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create array using your existing values (using [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)) and [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to create a new range from 1 to the size of your array

[Working example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec881ac76f1c8523f29a73c2926c7c99d8a7a848)

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes start at 0. If you really wanted to have the array start with one, you could explode it, then copy it to another array with your indexes defined as starting at 1 - but why?

Comment: This is unhelpful, and better qualifies as a comment on the question versus an answer.  Please consider deleting this answer as it only acts as page bloat.  Downvoted.

Comment: PDO's `bindValue()` parameters are 1-indexed and it would be directly useful to set up the array keys this way to iterate through and set all of the bindValue parameters and values without additional handling.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this possibly (untested)

```
$newArray=array_unshift($temp,' ');
unset($newArray[0]);
```

Comment: This is the right way to think about it, but Lloyd Watkin is one function fewer because he prepends the `$data` string with an extra delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible using explode.

```
for($i = count($temp) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) 
    $temp[$i + 1] = $temp[$i];
unset($temp[0]);
```

Comment: Your leading statement is incorrect.  Some of the best two-step methods to solve this question incorporate `explode()`.  Try not to mislead SO readers with such an assertion.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't do it directly, but this will do what you're after:

```
$temp=explode(',',',' . $data);
unset($temp[0]);
var_dump($temp);
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(6) "test_1"
  [2]=>
  string(7) " test_2"
  [3]=>
  string(7) " test_3"
}
```

Comment: quickly copy and pasted from terminal

Answer (score 0):

Lloyd Watkin's answer makes the fewest function calls to achieve the expected result.  It is certainly a superior answer to ManseUK's method which uses four functions in its one-liner after the string has been exploded.

Since this question is nearly 5 years, old there should be something valuable to add if anyone dare to chime in now...

I have two things to address:

1. The OP and Lloyd Watkins both fail to assign the correct delimiter to their explode method based on the sample string.  The delimiter *should be* a comma followed by a space.

   Sample Input:

   ```
   $data="test_1, test_2, test_3";
   ```
2. No one has offered a one-liner solution that matches Lloyd's two-function approach.   Here that is: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9cf622ff3a268394d520e348e40c1580bbfec59))

   ```
   $temp=array_slice(explode(", ",", $data"),1,null,true);
   ```

   This two-function one-liner prepends the `$data` string with a comma then a space before exploding it.  Then `array_slice` ignores the first empty element,  and returns from the second element (`1`) to the end (`null`) while preserving the keys (`true`).

   Output as desired:

   ```
   array(
       1 => 'test_1',
       2 => 'test_2',
       3 => 'test_3',
   )
   ```

Comment: @lgt The other answers on this page range from inefficient to argumentative to incorrect.  Please consider switching the accepted answer to mine because future SO readers may be confused, misled, and/or might copy/paste inefficient code.